# How to count total size of directory, and why `du` output differs between copies of directory?

Tags: linux, disk-space, ext4, du

Because I am clearly missing something here:

```
 $ cp -a CENTOS-chroot 1
 $ cp -a CENTOS-chroot 2
 $ cp -a CENTOS-chroot 3
 $ cp -a CENTOS-chroot 4
 $ du --block-size=1 -s 1 2 3 4
6320304128  1
6320304128  2
6320234496  3
6320238592  4
```

This happens both on HDD and NVME SSD with ext4 on two Linux machines (Manjaro and Centos7) I have.

Comment: Are you copying a directory with files being used? How far apart did you run the commands? Is it possible that you had a container/vm running out of your `CENTOS-chroot` while you were testing?

Comment: The `cp` commands were in fact run in parallel as `cp -a CENTOS-chroot 1 &`, etc., so the same file in original directory might've been read twice at the same time. But I just checked it with sequential order, and the sizes still differ. No VM or container is writing to the directory otherwise.

Comment: Try using `du -b`.

Comment: Run `diff -qr 1 3` to check that the file data is actually the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that `du` reports disk usage at the raw underlying filesystem level, not at the apparent "*file size*" level... see `--apparent-size`.

> `--apparent-size`
>
> print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually
> smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation,
> indirect blocks, and the like

See also `-b`, which might be a better option to giving `--block-size=1` *and* `--apparent-size` together:

> `-b`, `--bytes`
>
> equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1`

... so, does `du -bs ${dir}` produce better results?

---

Given that most / all filesystems are based on fixed-size blocks, it's very common to see the apparent "*File Size*" (i.e number of bytes you would be able to read from a file) differ to the actual space used on-disk (i.e: number of bytes consumed to store this file and its metadata).

For example:

- Small files will typically use more space than they "*should*"... on a filesystem with 4KiB blocks, it isn't possible to have a file use less than 4KiB of on-disk space, even if it only stores one byte.
- Large files are commonly constructed out of a number of "*extents*"... an extent will describe where to locate the data for a portion of the file. Extents consume disk space too.

  - In a filesystem without any fragmentation (i.e: large gaps of unused space), it's possible to have a "*large*" file with only one extent.
  - In a filesystem with lots of fragmentation (i.e: lots of data all over the place, leaving small gaps between data), that same "*large*" file may actually have a number of extents used to indicate where the data is stored.

---

It depends entirely on the order that files were palced on disk, and the algorithms that are used to seek out contiguous blocks of free space.

You could have a very space-efficient filesystem that continuously and carefully re-arranges all files such that they are perfectly tessellated like a well played Tetris board. The filesystem would end up spending a lot of time searching for suitable space, and the performance would suffer drastically.

Equally, you could have a very fragmentation-oriented filesystem, that just uses the first unused blocks, and skipping used blocks. Writing data on a first-gap basis is also going to decimate your performance.

Instead, we prefer to balance things, spending *some* time (*but not too much*) to seek out a contiguous block of unused space that will contain the entirety of the data we're trying to write.

The fragmentation level of a file isn't directly tied to the order that the copy commants were issued - in part because of the "*try, but not too hard*" approach outlined above.

---

In summary, the data stored in these two directories should be the same, but the disk usage (even for *the same data*) is unlikely to match perfectly.

There are a number of options to verify that the stored data is the same - try `diff` (no output is good, it'll report the changes):

```bsh
diff -qr "${src}" "${dst}"
```

---

To complicate this even further, it's possible that sparse files can use *significantly* less than expected:

```bsh
$ truncate -s 100M x
$ ls -l x
-rw-r--r-- 1 attie attie 104857600 Jul 14 17:15 x
$ du --block-size 1 x
0       x
$ du -bs x
104857600       x
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of extents and such! I did not take those into account, so I think I was expecting the size to stay the same because, the same files should occupy same amount of blocks. `-b` produces more predictable results, but sadly it won't  help my cause, since I actually need to account for blocks instead of logically accessible bytes (creating a file to be used as loop-device".

Comment: Remember that the loop-device will operate on the "_apparent file size_" too - just like a text editor... It doesn't care about the underlying layout of the file. Additionally, if you're making a filesystem image out of these directories, then you don't care about the underlying shape either - just the stored data / file content. It's very rare to genuinely be concerned about the physical / on-disk layout of a file.

Comment: I create a large file, "mount" it as loop device, then create an LVM from it via pvcreate, vgcreate etc., and then use mkfs.ext4 on it. Are you implying that in this case I can use `du -b` instead of `du --block-size=1` to calculate the minimal size of filesystem image file?

Comment: Using `losetup`? If so, then yes... you only really care about the "_apparent size_" of the file, not the "_actual disk usage_". The example I gave (`truncate -s 100M x`) will have a zero "_actual disk usage_", but will appear as a 100MiB block device. On the other hand, if you're creating a sparse file, filling it, and then using the reported usage as a hint at the smallest acceptable image size, then you're going about it in the wrong way... ([this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1555769/707676) might be helpful)

Answer (score 1):

The block and extent layout of an ext4 file system is dependent on the fill rate and fragmentation of the file system.

This implies, that a file system with more files on it will likely use up (slightly) different space for additional files, than on an empty file system. In your case, the 4th copy will take up more space than the 1st copy.

Comment: But it actually takes less space? `6320238592` for 4 < `6320304128` for 1. And it happens in the subdirectory in the same FS.

Comment: The same FS is exactly what I said. And I will edit "more" into "different"